# Android studio always garbled

Tags: android, android-studio

I have change the encode to UTF-8,so I got this problem,who can help me,I reinstalled it twice,but android studio1.4 Always garbled[image]

Comment: Try another version of android studio. I also once faced this problem due to OS i just reinstalled OS.

Answer (score 2):

You encountered this question because the font you selected is not support the displayed text in your IDE. You need to change the font of `Android Studio` IDE.

Which you are changing is the file encoding, It only changes the file encoding format, and have no relationship with the problem you're facing.

And change the font in the Setting->Appearance->Override default fonts:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I couldn't get past the splash screen for Android Studio. It was all garbled and I didn't know what button to press.  Turns out it was a non-standard font set-up as a default in windows.  The following REG file corrected it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"="segoeuib.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuiz.ttf"
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuii.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"="segoeuil.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"="seguisb.ttf"
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"="seguisym.ttf"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"=-
```