# Android studio fonts are messed up

Tags: android-studio

After some time today I opened my android studio and this is how fonts are look like

[image: one]

I've tried so hard to find fonts settings (pop up window in my screenshot) and changing fonts didn't help.

I also restarted my system after changing fonts and as you see didn't work.

I don't know why this happened but any idea how to fix this?

Comment: is this problem only in the android studio? whats about other software?

Comment: just android studio

Comment: May be this thread can help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523138/how-to-fix-android-studio-font-issues-in-ide-menu-and-labels

Comment: yes i just read that I don't have `ui.inf.xml` file and my font is set to `Verdana` yet nothing changed

Comment: **SOLVED** Found the answer in this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39596387/8490993)